# Why would you install your package in editable mode in order to test it?

Tags: python, testing, continuous-integration

Some of the packaging / testing guides like [Simon Willison's](https://simonwillison.net/2021/Nov/4/publish-open-source-python-library/) use editable install to test, locally which is understandable (kind-of) but also on CI which it seems a lot less so?

What are the advantages of using an editable install on CI, or when using something like `tox` to test locally in isolated environments?

Comment: You absolutely should not, if you are distributing your software with the idea it's going to be installed not in editable mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't, really. Editable installs are convenient, but can lead to erroneous results in testing. As noted in the [PyPA docs](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html) (original emphasis):

> Editable installs are **not a perfect replacement for regular installs** in a test environment. When in doubt, please test your projects as installed via a regular wheel. There are tools in the Python ecosystem, like tox or nox, that can help you with that (when used with appropriate configuration).

The behavior of `tox` (specifically, `tox` [v4 or later](https://tox--2601.org.readthedocs.build/en/2601/faq.html#tox-4-packaging-changes)) should be preferred. There is no particular advantage to editable installs, except perhaps that you won't need another test dependency, like `tox` and you won't have to configure tox. The big downside is that you may run into conditions (of which are [numerous](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html#limitations)) where you have tests pass when run as an editable install, but fail to work properly when a user installs it.